# Moving the selected rows from one DataTable to Other inPrimeFaces 3.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm new to PrimeFaces. In my project, I have a requirement to show 2 tables where user can select the rows and move to other datatable. In order to achieve this, can I use PickList component? If so, does it allow me show data with multiple columns. Any reference example is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you need to use picklist. you can acheive this using primefaces drag and drop.
[check it here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndTable.jsf)

Drag and Drop components have special integration with data components. you can integrate drag and drop components with your datatable.
lemme know if this helps ...:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, as per my requirement the proposed solution should depict PickList like look where user can click on ">" button to move the items from left box to right. Similarily, other options "<","<<",">>".